# How to return value from get method in Mocktail Flutter

Tags: flutter, testing

Probably a very dumb question.

Lets say I have a class

```
class Cat {
  Cat(fName, lName); 

  final String fName; 
  final String lName; 
  
  String get fullName => '$fName $lName'; 

}
```

When I mock this class for testing using Mocktail, how can I stub the mock so it returns the a full name value which is needed in the tests?

I have tried the following:

```
when(() => cat.fName).thenReturn('Kim');
when(() => cat.lName).thenReturn('The Cat');
```

and

```
when(() => cat.fullName).thenReturn('Kim The Cat');
```

Seems to result in a error: "Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method?"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's important to note that what you want to stub has to be a mock instance. So for example in your case you would have something like:

`class MockCat extends Mock implements Cat {};`

Then in setup or setup for all you'll have something like

```
  void main() {
      MockCat cat = MockCat();
      setUp(() {
       
       when(() => cat.fName).thenReturn('Kim');
      });
  }
```

Note, if your method is async you should use `thenAnswer`.

Something like:

```
class Cat {
  Future<String> asyncName() async {
    return Future.value('theName')
  }
}

 void main() {
      MockCat cat = MockCat();
      setUp(() {
       
       when(() => cat.fName).thenAnswer((_) async => 'Kim')thenAnswer((_) async => 'Le Cat');
      });
  }
```